# need help to identify the correct valve cover gasket for my old honda fit

Tags: honda, part-identification, gasket, fit

I have an old 2006 honda fit with a LA-GD1 engine (1.3L) (the one with the 8 spark plugs) and its leaking oil in the main/inner 4 spark plugs, i figured its because the valve cover gasket is failing (correct me if im wrong). So im trying to buy a new one. the problem is i dont know which one to buy and i can only order these things online. is it this one? 12341-PWA-000 or this one? 12341-PWC-000 or is it neither?

12341-PWA-000

[image: 12341-PWA-000]

12341-PWC-000

[image: 12341-PWC-000]

Comment: What is an "old Honda Fit"? You need to give us the year of the vehicle in order for us to try and help you.

Comment: its a 2006 honda fit. sorry about that

Comment: Which engine: 1.2L, 1.3L, 1.5L i-DSI, or 1.5L VTEC?

Comment: I can't find an LA-GD1 engine at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_L_engine. Searching for the part numbers on Hondas parts sites shows that 12341-PWA-000 is discontinued, but the PWC is available. Maybe call a dealer for a part number?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 think its the i-dsl one. sorry for being unsure. i almost have zero car knowledge and its a 2nd hand car, the user manual is gone

Comment: @PeteCon thanks for the info. maybe ill try contacting a dealer for this

Comment: Keep in mind that while a leaking valve cover gasket may be caused by failure of the valve cover gasket, it's not uncommon to be caused by failure of an ancillary system (e.g., the PCV systems on VW 4-cylinder motors from the early 2000s). If another system's failure is causing the VCG to fail, you should address the underlying cause, otherwise even a new VCG will fail as well.

Comment: @David thank you as well. ill check everything now before throwing in new parts

Comment: @J.Doe You're welcome. That is indeed the prudent course of action.

Comment: LA-GD1 is a 1.3L